# How to switch to a tab in mobile Safari without it reloading?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

Many times when I'm on Safari on my iPhone and I choose to switch to a new tab, instead of just displaying its contents, it reloads the entire tab. Is there any way to switch to the tab and prevent it from reloading the tab?

I tried turning off all network connections, but it still attempts to load the tab, fails, and shows a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottleneck is the available free memory (RAM) on the iPhone.

If Safari starts running out of memory it will flush the contents of older tabs meaning they have to reload when you switch back to them.

If you have too many tabs open, or you simply have multiple tabs that each have a large web page in them, Safari will reload when you switch back to another tab. There’s no fixed limit; it depends on the combined size of the HTML + all assets each web page you have open and on the total number of tabs you have open.

As the available RAM in new iPhone models increases, this will become less and less of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you by any chance have any references/sources that corroborate this and perhaps go into further detail?

Comment: I remember reading about this when the iPad 2 came out — it was one of the examples that showed how more RAM impacts the user experience & performance. Anyhow, here’s a similar discussion on the Apple forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2774294?start=0&tstart=0 Apparently, alternative iOS browsers like iCab can do what you want, at the cost of a bit less optimal memory management.